# AudioFileCreateWithURL failed('wht?')

Tags: c, cocoa, core-audio

I'm trying to record sound using Audio Queue, but every time I want to write to file I get the message `AudioFileCreateWithURL failed('wht?')`. I haven't been able to find a corresponding solution to this error, for I haven't found a similar (`wht?`) error elsewhere. I acquired the code from Apple's official guide for Audio Queue programming and it looks like this:

```
char* filePath = "Users/linus/voicies/output.wav";
CFURLRef myFileURL = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation( // 1
    NULL,                                                     // 2
    (const UInt8 *) filePath,                                 // 3
    strlen (filePath),                                        // 4
    false                                                     // 5
);
OSStatus err = AudioFileCreateWithURL(
    myFileURL,
    kAudioFileWAVEType,
    &recordFormat,
    kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
    &recorder.recordFile
);

CheckError(err);
```

in which `CheckError` finds the corresponding error, which is (`wht?`). I have no idea what that means and what I must do to make it happen, since the code I have used is almost identical to the sample codes. I appreciate any kind of clue.

Comment: Your file path is relative, since it doesn't start with a slash (`/`). Therefore, it's sensitive to the current working directory. Presumably, the path is invalid unless the current working directory is the root of the file system. Try just adding the slash to make the path absolute (e.g. `char* filePath = "/Users/linus/voicies/output.wav";`).

Comment: IME, `wht?` typically indicates a bad/unsupported file format. Or perhaps also a missing file, as @KenThomases indicated.